# Why can't I run JavaScript programs using the node command on the terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I just started learning JS and have been finding it difficult to run JS code using the node command on the terminal. I've tried everything but it doesn't show anything. [Using node command doesn't show anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYqjI.png)

What should I do?

Tried to re-install Node.js a couple of times but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Answer (score 4):

To print something on the terminal, use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. For example, in your case, replace `alert(message)` with `console.log(message)` and then it will print on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many issues while you try to run the node.js command.
First reason :- To use alert() you must link your tut1.js with your html file. in script tag.
second reason : - To print something on the terminal, use console.log() instead of alert(). For example, in your case, replace alert(message) with console.log(message) and then it will print on the terminal.

third reason:- check your package.json file. check the start key and its value

> code here

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node tut1.js.js",
    "start": "node tut1.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first create a file with names like index.js and enter this text in the terminal
but each time you run this command you can use nodemon
he will do it for you.
link info:[1]: https://nodemon.io/

Comment: Hi, if you look at the screenshot, clearly the author has already started the script. So, your answer does not address the problem